# Java - Get icon based on file-name extension

Tags: java, swing, icons

I want to get the default icon for different file extension.
Important: I don't have a `java.io.File`, but a `String` that contains the filename + file extension. So something like this:

```
Icon ico = javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);
```

won't work.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: What does your `file` string look like?

Comment: It depends on the file that I want to download from my FTP. Most of the time it will be something like .zip or .txt. Even if it's .tar.gz I think it wouldn't mean a lot to just have .gz´.

Comment: `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(new File(file))` ?

Comment: When I store `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(new File(file))` in an icon variable and do something like JLabel.setIcon(icon) nothing appears but the Label is displayed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to use the String constructor on a file to create the file. For instance:

```
File file = new File(filenameString);
```

And then go from there.

There are probably some caveats to this, so you may want to double-check the docs.

Comment: This is what I ended up with:

`JLabel lb = new JLabel(fileName);
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Robin\\Desktop\\temp\\" + fileName);
file.createNewFile();
Icon ico = javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);
file.delete();
lb.setIcon(ico);`

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing for all people having the same struggle:

```
lb = new JLabel(fileName);
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Robin\\Desktop\\temp\\" + fileName);
file.createNewFile();
Icon ico = Javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);
file.delete();
lb.setIcon(ico);
```

File is created - the icon gets stored in the ico variable - file is deleted - icon is set

Note: Created file is empty so it doesn't borther too much performancewise.